# ¿Cómo publicar localmente un reporte en PowerBi?

Tags: powerbi, report

Tengo un reporte desarrollado en PowerBI y necesito publicarlo para que otras personas puedan verlo, se que se lo puede subir a la nube a través de la opción de publicar en la web, sin embargo, estoy consumiendo datos de una base de datos oracle y para realizar la actualización el reporte necesita conectarse a oracle a través de un gateway(PowerBI gateway) pero esto no es posible debido a las restricciones del firewall de la empresa. ¿Existe alguna forma de publicar localmente o en intranet los reportes de PowerBI para que otras personas puedan verlo?

Answer (score 1):

La única forma de hacerlo es adquiriendo el [Servidor de Informes](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/es-es/report-server/).

Pero requiere de una licencia de [SQL Server Enterprise](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing) o bién de una licencia [Premium de Power BI EM](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/Power-BI-Premium-EM-pricing/td-p/632425) que tiene un precio a partir de [$4.200 mensuales](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/es-es/calculator/).

El problema real que tienes no es la publicación, es la actualización de datos. Los datos están en la nube y sin Power BI Premium, siempre acabas requiriendo actualizar los datos en el servidor de reportes de Power BI.